# Proc sql how to pull member records greater than 18yrs using birthday

Tags: sas

column how the birthdate is listed

birth_date
1933-11-25
1924-04-04
1951-11-15
1933-11-25
1956-11-20
1956-11-20
1942-02-25
1945-05-03
1954-09-16
1956-04-09
1952-02-15
1952-02-15

proc sql;
select * from table
where birth_date>18years;
quit;

Comment: To know someone's age you need more than just the date of birth.  You need their age at particular point in time.   Do you want to calculate their age as of today? Or do you have some other date variable you want to use?

Comment: I want to calculate as of today()

Answer (score 0):

You can use INTNX() function to find the cutoff date.

```
where birth_date <= intnx('year',today(),-18,'same')
```

Comment: thank you so much :) what does 'same' indicate

Comment: Which specific point it the target interval INTNX() should calculate.  You can specify BEGINNING or END.  For this application you probably want to use the same day of the year.  Experiment and see if it works better using month as the interval instead.  If you use month then use -12*18 as the offset.